# JavaFx application not Hiding from doc for Mac OSX

Tags: javafx

I need to hide the dock icon of my javafx application. In a normal java application this can be achieved by the following property in info.plist file:

LSUIElement
    1
But this is not working for my application.
I tried this with team-viewer and it works but not working with my application.
Here is the detail of my Info.plist file. please suggest what I am doing wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
  <key>LSUIElement</key>
  <string>1</string>
  <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
  <string>10.7.4</string>
  <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
  <string>English</string>
  <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
  <string>IsmSnapshotGenerator</string>
  <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
  <string>IsmSnapshotGenerator.icns</string>
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
  <string>ismsnapshotgenerator.ismsnapshotgeneratorserver</string>
  <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
  <string>6.0</string>
  <key>CFBundleName</key>
  <string>IsmSnapshotGenerator</string>
  <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
  <string>APPL</string>
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
  <string>${application.version}</string>
  <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
  <string>????</string>
  <!-- See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/SubmittingToMacAppStore/_index.html
       for list of AppStore categories -->
  <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
  <string>unknown</string>
  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
  <string>100</string>
  <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
  <string>Copyright © 2004-2013 Image Stream Medical, the Image Stream Medical Logo, DualStream and nStream are Trademarks of Image Stream Medical. This computer program is protected by copyright law and international treaties. Unauthorized reproduction or distribution of this program, or any portion of it, may result in severe civil and criminal penalties, and will be prosecuted to the maximum extent possible under the law. </string>
  <key>JVMRuntime</key>
  <string>jdk1.7.0_51.jdk</string>
  <key>JVMMainClassName</key>
  <string>com.javafx.main.Main</string>
  <key>JVMAppClasspath</key>
  <string></string>
  <key>JVMMainJarName</key>
  <string>IsmSnapshotGenerator.jar</string>
  <key>JVMPreferencesID</key>
  <string>ismsnapshotgenerator/ismsnapshotgeneratorserver</string>
  <key>JVMOptions</key>
  <array>
    <string>-Xms250M</string>
    <string>-Xmx1024M</string>
  </array>
  <key>JVMUserOptions</key>
    <dict>

    </dict>
  <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
  <string>true</string>
 </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I have the same issue and would be happy for any help :)